# Не освобождается память в PHP

Tags: php, память

```php
class A{}

echo memory_get_usage(), "\n";

$array = [];
for($i = 0; $i++ < 1000000;)
{
    $array[] = new A();
}

echo memory_get_usage(), "\n";

unset($array);

echo memory_get_usage(), "\n";
```

Почему освобождается не вся память, если наполнить массив объектами, а потом удалить этот массив?

Вывод в косноли:

```
565560
82504608
8946000
```

Было **565 560**, удалили переменную, и стало **8 946 000**, разница очень большая. Почему так? И как удалить оставшееся, если gc включен, и `gc_collect_cycles()` не помогает.

Comment: у вас тут и циклических ссылок нет, с чего ему помогать? зы: какую версию пхп используете?

Answer (score 2):

1. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.performance-considerations.php - тут подробности
2. Да, объекты простым `unset` не удаляются полностью, для их полного "удаления/очищения" нужно использовать присвоение к null (но могу ошибаться, ибо теорию толком не помню)

**UPD** Если создание каждый раз нового объекта не критично, вы можете передавать **экземпляр** класса (как обычную переменную), тогда память освободится ВСЯ.

```
class A{}

$a = new A();

echo memory_get_usage(), "\n";

$array = [];
for($i = 0; $i++ < 1000000;)
{
    $array[] = $a;
}

echo memory_get_usage(), "\n";

foreach($array as $arr){

    $arr=null;
    unset($arr);
}

unset($array);

echo memory_get_usage(), "\n";

//365944 36017608 365944
```

Нашел старую статью про объекты и память, можно почитать на досуге - https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/255237/

Comment: С null что-то тоже не работает =(